# How to set x axis title and title on seaborn distplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
dt = pd.DataFrame({'var':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]})
```

And I am creating a dist plot like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
fig = sns.distplot(dt['var'], norm_hist=False, kde=False, bins=3).get_figure()
```

And then I am saving this plot to a pdf

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
pdf = PdfPages('foo.pdf')
pdf.savefig(fig, height=10, width=18, dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.5)
plt.close()
```

How can I change the title and x_axis title at the plot ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `pyplot`
Try:

```
plt.xlabel("x-axis")
plt.title("title")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = sns.distplot(dt['var'], norm_hist=False, kde=False, bins=3).get_figure()

plt.title("something")
plt.xlabel("something")
plt.ylabel("something") 


from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
pdf = PdfPages('foo.pdf')
pdf.savefig(fig, height=10, width=18, dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.5)
plt.close()    #if you want to present on jupyter you need to comment this out.
```